# How to create recursive Gradle task?

Tags: gradle

I would like to create a task in the root project such that when the task is executed, it executes tasks of the same name within the sub-projects only for those sub-projects that have tasks of that name.

I don't want to hard-code the names of the tasks since more sub-projects may be added later.

```
task checkArtifacts
subprojects.findAll { subproject ->
  subproject.getTasksByName('checkArtifacts', false)
}.forEach { task ->
  checkArtifacts.dependsOn(task)
}
```

doesn't work since it looks like it forces the configuration stage to end and breaks some plugins that make configuration stage changes.

```
task checkArtifacts
afterEvaluate {
  subprojects.findAll { subproject ->
    subproject.getTasksByName('checkArtifacts', false)
  }.forEach { task ->
    checkArtifacts.dependsOn(task)
  }
}
```

emits `Could not determine the dependencies of task ':checkArtifacts'.`

Answer (score 2):

There's some methods in [DomainObjectCollection](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DomainObjectCollection.html) which are  applied to future updates to the collection.

Eg `all`

> Executes the given closure against all objects in this collection, and any objects subsequently added to this collection. The object is passed to the closure as the closure delegate. Alternatively, it is also passed as a parameter.

And `matching`

> Returns a collection which contains the objects in this collection which meet the given closure specification. The returned collection is live, so that when matching objects are added to this collection, they are also visible in the filtered collection.

So something like

```
subprojects {
    tasks.matching { it.name == 'checkArtifacts' }.all { task ->
        rootProject.tasks.checkArtifacts.dependsOn task
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need this task defined at the root all?  If you just call the task 'checkArtifacts' at the root, it will run it for every subproject that has it defined.  There is no need to make the extra task.

If you do need to do it, I'd try something more like this using [TaskContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html):

```
task checkArtifacts

subprojects {
    tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
        if (task.name == 'checkArtifacts') {
            rootProject.tasks.checkArtifacts.dependsOn task
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. I had forgotten to mention that I want another rootProject task to depend on this one.